# Boolean method creates exception

Tags: java

I have created a Boolean method called `trainer()` inside the class `Trainer` which extends the abstract class `Employees()`. This method returns true if the Employee inside the list is a trainer and then it prints it. But when I execute the program there seems to be an exception with the Boolean method `trainer`. As for the `ItemEmployees` this is a class which expands a class called `Item()`.

If needed I can provide both their codes. But I do not think the problem is in those classes.

The following is written within the main class:

```
Node firstnode = list.getFirst(); 
ItemEmployees t = (ItemEmployees) firstnode.getValue(); 
for(Node tmp=firstnode; tmp!=null; tmp=tmp.getNext())
{
        if(tmp.getValue()!=null)
         {
                Employees e = t.keye();
                if( e.trainer() )
                {
                        e.print();
                }
        }
}
```

Now this is inside the `Trainer()` class:

```
public boolean trainer()
{
    return true;
}
```

Exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:348)

Line 348 is

```
if( e.trainer() )
```

Comment: What's the exception? Can you share the stacktrace please?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:348)

Comment: You say, that Trainer extends the Employee(I guess that's what your "expands" means) and the `trainer()` method is in Trainer. You cannot call it on Employee

Comment: Most likely `e` is null.

Comment: What line is 348 in your code?

Comment: @MarArg In future please add the extra details by editing the question, it makes the question clearer ;-)

Comment: Did you mean `Employees e = ((ItemEmployees) tmp.getValue()).keye()`?

Comment: No because keye() is inside a class called ItemEmployees() and not int the Employees() class.(When i tried it it appeared "Cannot cast from Employees to ItemEmployees")

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most certainly that either `e` is null, or failing that, `trainer()` is returning null. I haven't seen your entire class, but your `trainer()` method looks tentative but solid. Check your initialization.

If, by the time you're finished, you must have `trainer()` return a value that may be unknown (null), consider using Java 8's `Optional` class to avoid null pointer exceptions and make your code a little easier to debug. (See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html and http://java.dzone.com/articles/optional-java-8-cheat-sheet).